# Не получается перезаписать значения с одного массива в другой

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress

Есть массив с заполненными полями, где $products - еще один вложенный в него массив

```
$products = array();
foreach($order->get_items() as $item)
{
    $products[] = [
        'name' => $item['name'],
        'qty' => $item['qty'],
        'price' => $item['price']
    ];          
}
$args = array(
    'storeid'           => $storeid,        
    'total'             => $total,
    'products'          => $products
);
```

Если вывести `print_r($args);` то все отлично отображается по структуре, но как только пытаюсь собрать другой массив по параметрам ключ-значение - выводится массив с ключами и пустыми значениями

```
$args_array = array();
   foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
if(!$key['products']) {
    $args_array[] = '<input name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
}
else {
      foreach ($key['products'] as $item) {
           $args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$item['name'].'" />';
           $args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="'.$item['qty'].'" />';
           $args_array[] = '<input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$item['price'].'" />';
      }
}
    }
```

Comment: Работает, хоть и с notice (PHP очень интересен, он все строки, которые не являются переменными или объявленными константами, транслирует как константы, содержащие этот текст).

Comment: @Ivan Solntsev описался - подправил

Comment: @Visman упростил без функции

Comment: @Norritt есть идеи?

Comment: Ну, что-то вы, @Вася, код в вопросе изменили до неузнаваемости. Научитесь правильно формулировать вопросы наконец-то и не сбивать людей с толку.

Comment: @Visman так я же дополнил код, чтобы ответить на ваши вопросы "В каком виде вы хотите увидеть такой массив в коде?
Вася, так почему в приведенном коде нет объявления переменных $storeid, $total, $products." Так вам не нравится, если описанием задавать тоже не нравится - я уже сам теряюсь как задавать вопросы.. моя головная боль в том, что не знаю почему не могу получить значения $args_array[]

Comment: @Вася, вы тут не при чем. Настроение мне попортил тот, кто минус влепил. Ждите, не я же один на ваш вопрос отвечать буду. Появится тот кто ответит, поставите ему отметку "правильный ответ" и +1 и все будет Ok.

Comment: @Visman это я реально туплю - код верный, только var_dump не может прочитать скрытые поля `hidden` блин..) вопрос закрыт!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код полностью рабочий

```
$storeid = 1;
$total = 50;
$products = 'abc';

$args = array(
    'storeid'           => $storeid,
    'total'             => $total,
    'products'          => $products
);

$args_array = array();
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    $args_array[] = '<input name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
}

var_dump($args_array);
```

Результат

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '<input name="storeid" value="1" />' (length=34)
  1 => string '<input name="total" value="50" />' (length=33)
  2 => string '<input name="products" value="abc" />' (length=37)
```

**UPD** Уточнение про массив: Если значением элемента является массив, то преобразуем его в строку для вывода с помощь функции [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
$storeid = 1;
$total = 50;
$products = array('abc', 'dfg', 'aaa');

$args = array(
    'storeid'           => $storeid,
    'total'             => $total,
    'products'          => $products
);

$args_array = array();
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = implode(',', $value);
    }

    $args_array[] = '<input name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />';
}

var_dump($args_array);
```

Результат

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '<input name="storeid" value="1" />' (length=34)
  1 => string '<input name="total" value="50" />' (length=33)
  2 => string '<input name="products" value="abc,dfg,aaa" />' (length=45)
```

**UPD2**

**На переписанный автором вопрос отвечать не буду. Можете минусовать ответ.**

Comment: я писал `где $products - еще один вложенный в него массив`

Comment: @Вася, так почему в приведенном коде нет объявления переменных `$storeid`, `$total`, `$products`. Я например не увидел это уточнение в тексте.  Norritt думаю тоже. Уточняющий вопрос: В каком виде вы хотите увидеть такой массив в коде?

Comment: @Вася, обновил ответ.

Comment: а я добавил код) @Visman сенкс, только чуть по-другому вывод необходим - из описанию думаю понятно

Comment: Тот слишком умный человек, который поставил -1 за ответ, сначала бы посмотрел на код в вопросе до его переписывания автором.